# Discord.py, on_raw_reaction_add add_roles not working

Tags: python, discord.py, roles

I'm trying to make a discord bot which can add a role to a member who react... There is what i've done so far.. The first part is working, but i can't add the role when react. Was trying a lot of thing and i'm lost.. Can you help me? Thanks a lot :)

```
import discord
from discord import Embed
from discord.utils import get
from discord.utils import find
from discord.ext import commands
 
 
class color(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
 
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Module "Color" prêt.')
 
    @commands.command()
    async def color(self, ctx, help="permet d'assigner des rôles en fonction de la couleur choisie"):
          embed = (Embed(title="Choisis ton rôle! Réagis avec la couleur que tu désires !", description="Quelle couleur veux-tu être?")
                   .add_field(name=":blue_heart:", value="Team Bleue", inline = False)
                   .add_field(name=":heart:", value="Team Rouge", inline = False)
                   .add_field(name=":green_heart:", value="Team Vert", inline = False)
                   .set_footer(text=f'Made by {ctx.author.display_name}'))
 
          message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
          emojis = ['', '❤️', '']
          for emoji in emojis:
                await message.add_reaction(emoji)
 
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        member = payload.member
        if member.bot:
            return

        guild = self.bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="TeamBleue")
        member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)

        if str(payload.emoji) == '':
            await member.add_roles(role, reason="TeamBleue")
        
 
    @color.error
    async def color_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.NotOwner):
            await ctx.send('''Désolé, tu n'as pas le droit de faire ceci :)''', delete_after=3)
            await ctx.message.delete(delay=3)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(color(bot))
```

Comment: Can you add your traceback?

Comment: how can i have it? :o

Comment: Your console output when you try to add the role.

Comment: "Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/axel/cogs/color.py", line 35, in on_raw_reaction_add
    guild = bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
NameError: name 'bot' is not defined"

Comment: sorry, don't know why i had nothing right before

Comment: Please add that to your existing code and put it in the right format although the error speaks for itself. You did not define `bot` but use it in your function.

Comment: Sorry, have edited the post. it's self.bot & payload.emoji. And now, i have no traceback when i add a reaction

Comment: Try reacting the blue heart emoji and print debugging to figure out where your code is going wrong

Comment: Hey! I think the issue is that the "if payload.emoji == '':" isn't good. There is nothing happenning when i react on... If I remove the payload, emoji isn't defined, and a react tell me so.
I don't know how to check what is wrong more, but i really think that's my mistake

Comment: Ok, found :) the solution was "if str(payload.emoji) == "" :" 

If someone can explain me why, it'll be great :)

Answer (score 0):

We have to use "str(emoji)" for the classic emojis :)

Answer (score 0):

It may sound a bit weird, but you have to do it with `payload.emoji.name`. Revised:

```
import discord
from discord import Embed
from discord.utils import get
from discord.utils import find
from discord.ext import commands
 
 
class color(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
 
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Module "Color" prêt.')
 
    @commands.command()
    async def color(self, ctx, help="permet d'assigner des rôles en fonction de la couleur choisie"):
          embed = (Embed(title="Choisis ton rôle! Réagis avec la couleur que tu désires !", description="Quelle couleur veux-tu être?")
                   .add_field(name=":blue_heart:", value="Team Bleue", inline = False)
                   .add_field(name=":heart:", value="Team Rouge", inline = False)
                   .add_field(name=":green_heart:", value="Team Vert", inline = False)
                   .set_footer(text=f'Made by {ctx.author.display_name}'))
 
          message = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
          emojis = ['', '❤️', '']
          for emoji in emojis:
                await message.add_reaction(emoji)
 
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        member = payload.member
        if member.bot:
            return

        guild = self.bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="TeamBleue")
        member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)

        if payload.emoji.name == '':
            await member.add_roles(role, reason="TeamBleue")
        
 
    @color.error
    async def color_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.NotOwner):
            await ctx.send('''Désolé, tu n'as pas le droit de faire ceci :)''', delete_after=3)
            await ctx.message.delete(delay=3)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(color(bot))
```